# To "have something in mind", in German

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english

Recently I was having a conversation which made me question how one expresses, "to have something in mind", as in, "to think something would be a good suggestion". I was always under the assumption that this was expressed as "etwas im Sinn haben". For example:

Person A: I'd like to travel somewhere sunny.

Travel agent: I have a great location in mind!

Mein Übersetzungsversuch:

Person A: Ich möchte reisen, irgendwohin, wo es sonnig ist.

Reiseberater: Ich habe einen tollen Ort im Sinn!

Is this the wrong way to express this? Or is "etwas im Sinn haben" the same as "etwas vorhaben"?

Comment: *…etwas im Sinn haben…* is usually understood as *tongue in cheek*.

Answer (score 6):

Your translation would fit quite well if the travel agent, knowing that the customer would ask this question, had already thought about it in advance (not very likely in this scenario).
The best *idiomatic* translations for "I have a great location in mind!" would be

> - Ich wüsste da einen tollen Ort.
> - Da fällt mir ein toller Ort ein.

Comment: Thanks! Would you then say that, "etwas im Sinn haben" is better translated as, "I've HAD something in mind"? That is, you have been considering a particular option for a little while already?